# i have an error in column application can't get data from some column in table android

Tags: android, sqlite

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
   String CREATE_TABLE= "CREATE TABLE " + Constants.TABLE1_NAME + "(" +
           Constants.KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "+Constants.EMP_NAME+" Text, " + Constants.PHONE_NUMBER_NAME+" TEXT, " + Constants.EMP_ID+" INT ); ";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
}

public int getEmpId(){
    int EmpId=0;
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();

    String query="SELECT "+Constants.EMP_ID +" FROM "+Constants.TABLE1_NAME;
    Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery(query,null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst())
    {EmpId=cursor.getInt(0);}

    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    return EmpId;

}
```

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: id (code 1):
>   , while compiling: SELECT id FROM info
>                                                                                                    at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native
>   Method)
>                                                                                                    at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
>                                                                                                    at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
>                                                                                                    at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
>                                                                                                    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
>                                                                                                    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
>                                                                                                    at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
>                                                                                                    at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1316)
>                                                                                                    at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1255)
>                                                                                                    at Data.DatabaseHandeler$override.getEmpId(DatabaseHandeler.java:61)
>                                                                                                    at
>   Data.DatabaseHandeler$override.access$dispatch(DatabaseHandeler.java)
>                                                                                                    at Data.DatabaseHandeler.getEmpId(DatabaseHandeler.java:0)
>                                                                                                    at
>   imageview.example.maged.taskforseautomation.MainActivity$override.suresignin(MainActivity.java:60)
>                                                                                                    at
>   imageview.example.maged.taskforseautomation.MainActivity$override.onClick(MainActivity.java:75)
>                                                                                                    at
>   imageview.example.maged.taskforseautomation.MainActivity$override.access$dispatch(MainActivity.java)
>                                                                                                    at
>   imageview.example.maged.taskforseautomation.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:0)
>                                                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
>                                                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
>                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>                                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                                    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

Comment: If you added the column only later, you can uninstall your app to remove the old database and create a new one with the updated schema.

Answer (score 0):

In your table you did not create colum id, and you are specifying in your SQL query, so thats why its showing error.
Try loggin your table create query and watch clearly

Comment: can you write your mean answer ??

Comment: you can visit here, it will give you the complete info aboutt SQLite
http://yasirameen.com/2016/02/android-sqlite-database-login-system/
Or you can use Realm

http://yasirameen.com/2016/02/android-sqlite-database-login-system/

Answer (score 0):

use this as your select statement
`String query="SELECT "+Constants.KEY_ID +" FROM "+Constants.TABLE1_NAME;`

There is no column `Constants.EMP_ID`in  your database schema. Check your Create table command.

Comment: i made that but i didn't receive any data public class MainActivity extends 

    private void suresignin(){
        Information info=new Information();
        String empId=EmpID.getText().toString();
        int EMPID=Integer.parseInt(empId);
        info.setEmpId(EMPID);
        if(db.getEmpId()==info.getEmpId()){

            Log.v("this is True data","good again");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),db.getEmpId(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


    }

Comment: Did you insert something in the database? Where is your insert function?

Comment: private void SaveInfoTodb(){
        Information info=new Information();

        String empId=EmpID.getText().toString();
        int EMPID=Integer.parseInt(empId);
        info.setEmpName(empName.getText().toString());
        info.setEmpPhone(PhoneNum.getText().toString());
        info.setEmpId(EMPID);

        db.addinfo(info);
        db.close();

    }

Comment: need to see your db.addinfo() method? Or else verify that db has the entry by pulling out the database.

Comment: public void addinfo(Information info){

        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values=new ContentValues();

        values.put(Constants.EMP_NAME,info.getEmpName());
        values.put(Constants.KEY_ID,info.getEmpId());
        values.put(Constants.PHONE_NUMBER_NAME,info.getEmpPhone());

        db.insert(Constants.TABLE1_NAME,null,values);
        Log.v("first added in database","good");

        db.close();

    }

Comment: whare are you??